# Groovy methodMissing

Tags: groovy, mop

I have a closure within an object *Foo* and inside the closure i define a method called '*myStaticMethod*' that I want to resolve once the closure is called outside the object *Foo*.  I also happen to have 'on purpose' a static method within my object Foo with the same name. When I call the closure i set the 'resolve strategy' to DELEGATE_ONLY to intercept the call to *myStaticMethod* that is defined within the closure.

I tried to achieve that through *missingMethod* but the method is never intercepted. When i make the Foo.*myStaticMethod* non static, the method is intercepted. I don't quite understand why this is happening though my resolve strategy is set to DELEGATE_ONLY. having the *Foo.myStaticMethod* static or not shouldn't matter or I am missing something

```
class Foo {
   static myclosure = {
       myStaticMethod()
   }

   static def myStaticMethod() {}
}


class FooTest {
  def c = Foo.myclosure
  c.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_ONLY
  c.call()

  def missingMethod(String name, def args) {
    println $name
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Static methods unfortunately aren't intercepted by the closure property resolution.  The only way that I know to intercept those is to override the static metaClass invokeMethod on the class that owns the closure, ex:

```
class Foo {
   static myclosure = {
       myStaticMethod()
   }

    static myStaticMethod() {
       return false
   }
}

Foo.metaClass.'static'.invokeMethod = { String name, args ->
    println "in static invokeMethod for $name"
    return true
}

def closure = Foo.myclosure
assert true == closure()
```

Answer (score 5):

To solve the problem, I ended up overriding the invokeMethod right before calling the closure in FooTests

```
Foo.metaClass.'static'.invokeMethod = { String name, args ->
     println "Static Builder processing $name "
}
```

While trying to solve this problem, i discovered a very weird way to intercept missing static methods. Might be useful to some of you in the future.

```
 static $static_methodMissing(String name, args) {
    println "Missing static $name"
}
```

-Ken

Comment: +1 I didn't know about the $static_methodMissing trick, that could be useful

Comment: +1 for the static $static_methodMissing(String name, args) trick! It just made my day! I was able to implement a nice configuration DSL with it